# Scores with multi-label text classification do not sum up to one

Tags: python, probability, text-classification, normalize

I'm currently using Fast-BERT for multi-label text classification task.
As output, I obtain probabilities for each class :

```
('S5', 0.92626953125),
 ('S17', 0.0162200927734375),
 ('S8', 0.0150146484375),
 ('S9', 0.0142822265625),
 ('S10', 0.013275146484375),
 ('S6', 0.0129241943359375),
 ('S11', 0.01132965087890625),
 ('S3', 0.01129150390625),
 ('S14', 0.01078033447265625),
 ('S15', 0.01024627685546875),
 ('S12', 0.01016998291015625),
 ('S1', 0.010009765625),
 ('S16', 0.010009765625),
 ('S7', 0.0099334716796875),
 ('S2', 0.0095977783203125),
 ('S13', 0.007904052734375),
 ('S4', 0.0074310302734375)
```

As the probability is calculated class by class, the sum of all the probabilities is not equal to 1 but more than 1.
I would like to know, what could be the better solution to put all these probabilities on the same base (equal to 1 or 100 in percent) for an easier representation in charts.

I mention that I already try to "normalize"  my array with help of the Numpy library, but the result is just the same, the sum is always greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing multi-class and multi-label classification.

With multi-label classification, the goal is to assign some labels to the input (such as tags here at StackOverflow). There might be none correct, there might be many correct ones. The training objective is binary cross-entropy for each label and each label is predicted independently and can have a score between 0 and 1.

Given that you expect the scores to sum up to one, you probably wanted to use *multi-class classification*. In this case, exactly one label from a given set is assigned to the input. The output is a single categorical distribution and the training objective is categorical cross-entropy.

With Fast-Bert, just set `multi_label` to `False`.

Comment: In fact my classification task belongs to the multi label category. I have a serie of text where each text is related to 1 or many labels. I know that labels are predicted independently but I just would like to know if there is or are trick.s to transform these independent output in in a "global" interpretation easier to interpret and to represent is visual chart. I'm wondering for example if it could be possible and correct to transform these independent probabilities in mutual inclusive probabilities.